# process hidden field with jquery and calculate

Tags: php, jquery

I have an html table I've updated to use checkboxes to be able to delete multiple files:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Camera Name</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Video Size</th>
        <th>Video Length</th>
        <th>
            <button type="submit" class="deletebutton" name="delete_video" value="Delete" title="Delete the selected videos" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</button><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="radioselectall" title="Select All" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

 <?php

for($i=0;$i<$num_videos;$i++)
{
       //do stuff
       //Note: I'm looping here to build the table from the server
?>              
        <tr >
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo setlocalTime($result_videos[$i]["video_datetime"]); ?> 
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo ByteSize($result_videos[$i]["video_size"]); ?>
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                <?php echo strTime($result_videos[$i]["video_length"]); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="myform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
                <input type="checkbox" name="radioselect" title="Mark this video for deletion"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="video_name" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_name"]; ?>" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I started with first creating some jquery code to create a select all/deselect all button in the table heading and just a test to show I can find which boxes are checked.  That all works:

```
//selectall checkboxes - select all or deselect all if top checkbox is marked in table header
$("input[name='radioselectall']").change(function()
{
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
        $("input[type='checkbox']","td").attr('checked',true);
    } 
    else
    {
        $("input[type='checkbox']","td").attr('checked',false);
    }
});

//process checkboxes - which ones are on 
$(".deletebutton").click(function() {
    $("input[name='radioselect']:checked").each(function(i){
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

So the part where I'm stuck is I don't know where to go from here.  I need to pass all the video_names of all the videos selected (with the checkboxes).  `video_name` is part of a hidden field in my form.  So I need to pass that to my php function when the delete button is selected.  Not really sure how to tackle this.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution maybe:

Change your checkboxes to have a value of 1 and a name of $result_videos[$i]["video_name"]; in the table rows, make the form encapsulate the whole table.

Then on submit you can do something like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //Delete $key (the name) where $value == 1
}
```

Comment: Actually not sure I understand? The _POST would have to return only those checkboxes selected.  The javascript code knows what is checked off but not the server code?

Comment: If you give your checkboxes the name of `$result_videos[$i]["video_name"];` then these will be the keys in the POST array for these form elements, giving them a value of 1 and then checking for this will tell you if they were selected on submit.

Comment: Oh I get it. My problem is that for layout reasons I created the button outside the form. That means I need to create the form in javascript. I should probably redo the question. Thanks for the tip, for doing checkbox processing that will work.  I'll mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine if you want to access the hidden fields through jQuery at a given point but once you submit the form and lose the DOM, the PHP processing page will have no way to relate the selected checkboxes with the hidden fields as there is no consistent naming scheme.

One approach would be to use the loop counter to suffix the two in order to pair them up:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="radioselect_<?= $i ?>" title="Mark this video for deletion" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="video_name_<?= $i ?>" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_name"]; ?>" />
```

This would be good if you want to relate more than the two fields. Otherwise, you could just use the video_name as the value of the checkbox, as Ing suggested.